# Ember JS pass a value to a component property which includes HTML

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a very simple form field component, which displays an input with a label.
**components/form-field-input.hbs**

```
<label>{{label}}</label>
{{input value=value type=type }}
```

**template.hbs**

```
{{form-field-input label="Which of our products do you like the most?" type='Text' value=favouriteProduct}}
```

Say I want the word **products** in the label to link to another route in my app, which lists all of the products. Is there any way that this can be done?

I'm aware that the below cannot work, as the characters will just be escaped. Is there some way that the label could be built in the parent template's JS file and passed in?

```
{{form-field-input label="Which of our {{#link-to 'products'}}products{{/link-to}} do you like the most?" type='Text' value=favouriteProduct}}
```

Comment: why snippet ? when it is not used

Comment: did you consider using contextual component instead of passing html as property? i prefer to provide html content via contextual components instead of the way you explained. i can help if contextual components is an option.

Comment: Can you send your `label` property in parts like `label-pre`,`label-link`,`label-post`,`forwardRouteName` and then combine them in your component as needed.

Comment: Those are both possible solutions, but it may be easier to just place the label directly into the parent template, as this would be a once off type scenario.

Comment: Consider using `<label>{{yield}}</label>`, then call your component as `{{#form-field-input}}Which of our...{{/form-field-input`.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider installing `ember-cli-showdown`

```
ember install ember-cli-showdown
```

I your component.hbs file

```
<label>{{markdown-to-html label}}</label>
{{input value=value type=type }}
```

When using the component, you can directly place your regular HTML and will get rendered corectly.

```
{{form-field-input label="Which of our <a href='/products'>products</a> do you like the most?" type='Text' value=favouriteProduct }}
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Using component block, we can fix the above problem.

```
// hbs
{{#if hasBlock}}
    <label>{{yield}}</label>
{{else}} 
    <label>{{label}}</label>
{{/if}}
{{input value=value type=type }}

// using in template --  if need custom markup
{{#form-field-input type='Text' value=favouriteProduct}}
     {{#link-to 'products'}}products{{/link-to}} 
{{/form-field-input}} label="Which of our products do you like the most?"

// using in template --  if custom markup not needed
{{form-field-input label="Which of our products do you like the most?" type='Text' value=favouriteProduct}}
```